# Returning date in Google search results

Tags: search, google-search

Sometimes when I search for articles on the net, I would like to see the year of the article to see if it's relevant for my search. Is it possible to return that in the search result of Google search somehow, or can you recommend any other search engine with this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you want to know how recent the information is, you can use a Google “date” filter (via the Advanced Search page, under the “Date, usage rights, numeric range, and more” section).

Or, you can append specific &key=value variables to your search URL, as shown on the Unofficial Google Advanced Search guide page.  The guide, details several date-based or time-based options, such as date (past N months), [daterange](http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html#advDateRange) (between two Julian dates), or [tbs=qdr](http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html#advDatePeriod) (limit by time period).

I've had good results by appending daterange and limit by time period to my URL; mixed results with just date alone.  Here are some examples.

- Date: `http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby&hl=en&date=6`
- Date Range: `http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax&hl=en&daterange=2452821-2453187`
- Limit by time period: `http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby&hl=en&tbs=,qdr:m`

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but this is about viewing the date in the search result.

Comment: Well, Google provides the publication (i.e. upload) date of each linkable web page listed in its result set.  Apparently, the format of the Google search results can't be tailored to the user's liking.  Now, if one were using (for example) the Autonomy IDOL search engine, then an assortment of key-value vars can be appended to the URL to generate the user's desired format.

Comment: Ahh, in your last example the result is there. Thanks!